# One language to store-view

Tags: e-commerce, opencart

I have a Opencart installation with three languages active and a second store-view. English, German, Russian in the main store view. My second store is for the russian audience. 
Is it possible to have only one language assigned to my second store?
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Language selections by default are global, and cannot be selective based on the store. It's possible with some coding to do this however would require a number of core file edits

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jay. My intention why i just want one language is, is want yandex.ru to just index russian language. But i dont want to buy a multilingual url extension.

Comment: I see. Even a multilingual url extension won't actually fix the issue you're describing I'm afraid